# store and call variable in Powershell script

Tags: powershell

Below is the HTML DOM, I want to store DatePlannedStartTimeStamp value "01/24/2017 18:00" in a variable, print and call later

```
<TD class=dbData><SPAN onmouseover="ShowDay(this.innerHTML, 231320)" 
onmouseout=nd() id=DatePlannedStartTimeStamp>01/24/2017 18:00</SPAN></TD>
```

I tried below but it does not return any value

```
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -UseDefaultCredential
$WebPageText = ($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("a") | Where- 
Object{$_.ID -match "DatePlannedStartTimeStamp"}).innerText
echo $WebPageText
```

Not sure if my tagname is correct. I'm still learning powershell script, it would be great help if there is a way to it.

Comment: You're getting `a` elements, but the `id` attribute is part of a `span`.

Comment: I don't recommend parsing html yourself.  [There's a nice library called htmlagility](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack) you can use instead.  At that point you could read through the HTML like XML and use xPath:  `$html.SelectNodes('//span[@id="DatePlannedStartTimeStamp"]/text()').Value`

Comment: @DanielMann - Thank you for looking at it. So how would the script be? If you could please give an example from above that would be great.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - Thank you for the suggestion. I still have to explore your recommendation. Is there a wa that I can match the values */*/* *:* to get the date/time